# Passing parameter from parent to child component when using hierarchical routes with Angular2

Tags: angular, components

I have a route config as following:

```
export const ProjectRoutes: Route[] = [
  {
    path: 'projects',
    component: ProjectComponent,
    canActivate: [ScrollTop, AuthGuard],
    data: {
      roles: [Role.USER]
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'project/:id',
    component: ProjectDetailsComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: ProjectInfoComponent,
        canActivate: [ScrollTop, AuthGuard],
        data: {
          roles: [Role.USER]
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'tools',
        component: ProjectToolsComponent,
        canActivate: [ScrollTop, AuthGuard],
        data: {
          roles: [Role.USER]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Where the template of ProjectComponent is:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <priz-project-nav [project]="project"></priz-project-nav>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, as you can see, the `priz-project-nav` requires a project to render the navigation, but also `ProjectInfoComponent` and `ProjectToolsComponent` do.

So, what I am forced to do now is to load `project` object in each component separately, including in the parent one.
My question is, is it possible to pass loaded once object between components while each and every one of the child components is set under it's own route?

Answer (score 2):

Shared Service would be the way to go:

```
@Injectable()
export class YourSharedService {
    sharedRole: {
        // your properties here... e.g
        name: 'string'
    };
}
```

and inject that service in the constructor to all components that need to have access to the shared objec (or whatever)

```
constructor(private yourSharedService: YourSharedService......) {  }
```

Then you can access  it in every component like so:

```
localRole = this.yourSharedService.sharedRole;
```

and assign new values to it:

```
this.yourSharedService.sharedRole = localRole
```

and this goth bothways. All components that are assigned with this shared object get the value updated automatically if you make changes to it in some component.

The above is one solution. There are naturally other solutions ass well, e.g using Observables. More info about that is found in the [angular doc - component interaction](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service) I highly suggest you check out the doc in other issues too, the tutorial is very good in my opinion :)

Comment: I thought about it, and I do have a project service that actually responsible for fetching the object from the backend. But, it such case, the only way to NOT go to server every time is to cache it (which has it's own set of problems). If I simply create another object to hold shared stuff, I need to warry about updating the thing, instead of using built-in binding... So, I was hoping there is a smoother solution.

Comment: Why would you need to go to the server all the time? Once you get it once, use it in your components as much as you want and when you want to update or whatever in your backend, THEN you make the api call.

Comment: That is the great thing with a shared service, this is totally separate from your http-service, exactly to avoid constant server calls.

Comment: Yes, yes, now I understand :) Well, it is very possible you get other solutions and answers, this was my input and I like this approach personally :)