# Angular 2 clickable event is fired automatically without even clicking

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this class which helps to get data:

```
export class ItemsClass {
    name: string;
    desc: string;
    constructor(public name1:string, public desc1:string){
      this.name = name1;
      this.desc = desc1;
    }
}
```

And I have this component that use the class to generate data and display in a div:

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { ItemsClass } from './items-class';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  list:ItemsClass = new ItemsClass('Product 1', 'Electronics', 'SoldOut');
  @Output() EmitData = new EventEmitter<ItemsClass>();

  onSelected(list:ItemsClass){

    this.EmitData.emit(list);

  }
}
```

And here is clickable div:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <a class="btn btn-success">New Recipe</a>
</div>
<a href="#" class="list-group-item clearfix">
<hr>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <ul class="list-group">
    {{list.name}}
    </ul> 
    {{list.desc}}
  </div>
</a>
<app-items (click)="onSelected(list)" [list]="list"></app-items>
```

Now another component (items.component) is here as you see: `app-items`: which display the same data (for now) when I click on the div above:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-items',
  templateUrl: './items.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./items.component.css']
})
export class ItemsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() list;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

And here is the html script of it:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <img alt="" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <h1>{{list.name}}</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <button class="btn btn-success">To Shopping List</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <p>{{list.desc}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    Ingredients
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is the event (click) is fired automatically when I load the page without even clicking on the div and there is no error at the console. I am new to Angular 2.

Comment: please provide a plunker with your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is with using the Output. Output in this case would be if you want to emit data from child to parent, but you are having a parent-to-child communication here, so Input in child component is enough. More about that (and other component interactions) [Here.](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child)

A simplified version of your code:

Parent View:

```
<ul (click)="onSelected(list)">
   {{list.name}}
</ul> 

<!-- Here we show child only if there is a chosen list and pass that chosen list -->
<app-items *ngIf="chosenList" [chosenList]="chosenList"></app-items>
```

Parent Component:

```
// let's create a variable, that we will use as the list we are "sending" to child
chosenList;

list:ItemsClass = new ItemsClass('Product 1', 'Electronics', 'SoldOut');

onSelected(list:ItemsClass){
   this.chosenList = list; // set the selected list
}
```

and child view:

```
<div>
  <p>{{chosenList.name1}}</p>
</div>
```

Component:

```
@Input() chosenList;
```

### A working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RIa3bhkdsZEEaYbgHglq?p=preview)

EDIT: Since you cannot use `*ngIf` you can e.g use Subjects.

In your child declare a subject:

```
public static changesMade: Subject<any> = new Subject();
```

and in your child constructor the following, that subscribes to changes made in parent.

```
constructor() { 
  ChildComponent.changesMade.subscribe(res => {
    this.chosenList = res;
  });
}
```

and in your parent where you do the select, you emit this selected value to the child:

```
onSelected(list:ItemsClass){
  console.log(list.name)
  this.chosenList = list;
  ChildComponent.changesMade.next(this.chosenList);
}
```

### Forked plunker: [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ul2dX87ZDGWVlzLmHcxQ?p=preview)

If you need more communication between your components, I would suggest you would go ahead and use a shared service. One answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41511959/passing-parameter-from-parent-to-child-component-when-using-hierarchical-routes/41512051#41512051)

Comment: Thank you. Well currently I am not able to use ngIf. We still learning the basics. So the output is when sending data/values from child to parent. And input is sending from parent to child

Comment: But here we used the @Input in yhe child..so input is to send from child to parent. I am confused now

Comment: Updated my answer, NOW you can use this without ngIf. Check it out ;)

Comment: And as to your question. When we send data from parent to child, we use input. Input is noted in child, because when child is rendered, the input from parent is "put in" child. When a child emits an event we use output, because we "output" something to parent. That might be confusing, yes, since in both cases input and output are declared in the child, but there is a big difference though, hope I cleared it up a bit for you? :)

Comment: @droidnation Did this solution help you? :)